# SSRS accessing SQL ReportServer DB every 10 seconds

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

In SQL Profiler (for SPs), it seems my (single) SSRS Report Server instance is repeatedly accessing the ReportServer SQL DB every 10 seconds. The SSRS Stored Procedures being run are:
GetCurrentProductInfo
GetAllConfigurationInfo
GetAnnouncedKey
AnnounceOrGetKey

Is there any way to reduce the frequency of these SSRS requests ?

I've changed various settings in RSReportService.config, inc. PollingInterval (from 10s to 28800s), but none of this has had any effect on the above, even after re-start, re-boot.

Thanks for info/help.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: ...it's just server load prioritizing/optimizing really...although the SSRS requests are not particularly onerous, and SSRS in my environment is only rarely used to produce one-off reports, this SQL server isn't a standalone server for SSRS....it has a few (5 or so) other databases on it, and handles other quite a lot of other queries, tasks, processes etc., which the SSRS queries do frequently get in the way of.... 
is it really necessary to get this SSRS data every 10s  ?

Comment: How do the "the SSRS queries do frequently get in the way of" your other queries?  And if SSRS is lightly used you can always put a SQL Server instance on the SSRS server.

Comment: OK, thx, I'll do that.